# Vue + Django: создание блога. Вопрос по функционалу

Tags: django, vue.js, search

Добрый день! Каким образом лучше реализовать поиск и сортировку записей в блоге: используя Vue или силами Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё зависит от вашей реализации вывода записей.

К примеру если вы отдаете все записи на фронтенд и там уже Vue разбивает его на страницы и делает пагинацию - то в этом случае я бы делал на фронтенде и сортировку, все данные у нас есть, зачем лишний раз сервер трогать.

А вот если пагинацией занимается сервер - то и сортировку делать на нём стоит т.к. фронтенд не знает сколько всего записей и что там за данные.

С поиском тут от ситуации зависит и от данных, если к примеру вы выводите записи в блоге - вы же не отдаете на фронтенд и текст записи (я надеюсь), а только заголовок, дату и т.д. а поиск идёт по тексту записи - то нужно делать поиск на сервере, если же вы отдаете все поля сразу же по которым будет поиск - аналогично с сортировкой - делаем всё на фронте.

Это лично мое мнение, я бы делал так.